# scala Seq sortWith or sortBy with NaNs

Tags: scala, sorting

I've encountered some very strange sorting behaviour in scala (`2.11.8` and `2.12.1`) for `Seq[(Long, Double)]`. I am probably misunderstanding something fundamental.

Given a sequence with no `Double.NaN` values in it everything works as expected

```
Seq[(Long, Double)]((1L, 2.5D), (2L, 0D), (11L, 11D), (2L, 10D)).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
output >>> Seq[(Long, Double)] = List((11,11.0), (2,10.0), (1,2.5), (2,0.0))
```

if I add a tuple with a `NaN` in the sort column strange things happen

```
Seq[(Long, Double)]((1L, 2.5D), (2L, 0D), (3L, Double.NaN), (11L, 11D), (2L, 10D)).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
output >>> Seq[(Long, Double)] = List((1,2.5), (2,0.0), (5,NaN), (11,11.0), (2,10.0))
```

so it looks like nothing was done

if I swap the first two elements

```
Seq[(Long, Double)]((2L, 0D), (1L, 2.5D), (5L, Double.NaN), (11L, 11D), (2L, 10D)).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
output >>> Seq[(Long, Double)] = List((11,11.0), (2,10.0), (1,2.5), (2,0.0), (5,NaN))
```

the sorting works again??

The same is observed with just `Seq[Double]`

```
Seq[Double](2.5, 0, Double.NaN, 11, 10).sortWith(_ > _)
output >>> Seq[Double] = List(2.5, 0.0, NaN, 11.0, 10.0)

Seq[Double](0, 2.5, Double.NaN, 11, 10).sortWith(_ > _)
output >>> Seq[Double] = List(11.0, 10.0, 2.5, 0.0, NaN)
```

`.sortBy(_._2)` seems to work in all cases. Is this a bug in scala, or in my brain? I'm using scala `2.11.8` and `2.12.1` on `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91`.

**update**

it turns out that if I reverse the sort order then slightly more predictable things happen

```
Seq[(Long, Double)]((1L, 2.5D), (2L, 0D), (3L, Double.NaN), (11L, 11D)).sortWith(_._2 < _._2)
output >>> Seq[(Long, Double)] = List((2,0.0), (1,2.5), (3,NaN), (11,11.0))
```

but again adding a `NaN` in between breaks the sort

```
Seq[(Long, Double)] = List((2,0.0), (3,NaN), (1,2.5), (11,11.0))
output >>> Seq[(Long, Double)] = List((1,2.5), (3,NaN), (2,0.0), (11,11.0))
```

So `Seq.sortWith` or `.sortBy` just decides to give up when it sees a `NaN`?

---

On a slightly unrelated note, I came across this as `spark` was throwing an error (below) when I was trying to sort a sequence of tuples of the kind above. The results above are just from the `scala` REPL though, no spark involved there.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

---

there's also a related question on `.max` and `.min` with `NaN`s [min/max of collections containing NaN (handling incomparability in ordering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564120/min-max-of-collections-containing-nan-handling-incomparability-in-ordering)

Comment: For what it's worth, the sorting algorithm underneath is within `java.util.Arrays.sort`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Spark exception is actually a really good hint as to what's going on here: Spark assumes the comparison method defines a **[Total Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)** on the input set, which means, among other things, that for every two elements in the set:

```
A > B OR B > A
```

Now, the function `_ > _` is a Total Order for Doubles, but it **is not total** over the set of **all Doubles and NaN**. This can be seen using these simple tests:

```
scala> Double.NaN > 1.0
res19: Boolean = false

scala> Double.NaN < 1.0
res20: Boolean = false
```

So, `NaN` is not greater nor smaller than 1.0.

Back to the implementation of `sortWith` - I didn't check but I'm assuming it makes the same assumption, but instead of throwing an error when it's not the case, its results are simply made unpredictable (order-dependent) when totality is broken.

**EDIT**:

> So Seq.sortWith or .sortBy just decides to give up when it sees a NaN?

No, it simply returns "wrong" results because it makes wrong decisions due to the assumptions not being upheld. There's no *test* looking for `NaN`s  and giving up (as @TheArchetypalPaul commented: "Having sort deal with that would require it to check every value wasn't a NaN before comparison. Not worth it").

Comment: Beat me to it. I was just typing something very similar!

Comment: I get the transitivity part, I would still expect the language to treat `NaN`s in a consistent way, maybe don't change their position at all. Also, notice that it's not `sortBy` that is broken it's `sortWith`. This turns our to be because I'm using `>` and not `<` - see update above.

Comment: It's not just transitivity. Sorting assumes a total ordering. So either A <= C or C < A. for all A and C.  Comparison to NaNs doesn't follow that (due to the definition of floating point math). Having sort deal with that would require it to check every value wasn't a NaN before comparison. Not worth it.